# TensorFlow installation on CentOs7 - libcupti-dev equivalent?

Tags: tensorflow, centos7

I'm trying to install TensorFlow from sources (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) on CentOS7 with GPU support. Is there any equivalent for libcupti-dev library? Is it libcupti.so, or something else?

Comment: I think the point of the "-dev" requirement is just to get the headers. The .so itself looks like it's distributed by Nvidia too? At least, I have a version in /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64/libcupti.so. You can see the file list for the -dev package at https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libcupti-dev/filelist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building Tensorflow on Centos is painful. I'm working through the issues myself.

I had to reach out to an Nvidia engineer for the answer to this one. Installing the Nvidia toolkit creates the directory /usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64. The library libcupti.so is in there.